# Inserting and fetching python dict issues

Tags: python, mysql, json, dictionary

I need to insert the Dict in to Mysql Database and retrieve the same.

For that I have framed the code which is as follows:

```
    # dict json dumped for inserting to DB
    final_dict = json.dumps(big_dict)

    invoice_id = tenant_id

    # fina_dict exists
    if final_dict:

            logging.info("Inserting the necessary details into invoice_details table for tenant %s invoice period (%s to %s) Invoice date - %s" % (tenant_id, begin, end, date))
            sql = "INSERT INTO invoice_details(invoice_date, tenant_id, invoice_id, invoice_data, invoice_period_from, invoice_period_to) \
                           VALUES ( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )" % \
                           (date, tenant_id, invoice_id, final_dict, begin, end)
```

In above code basically big_dict is an Dict which I need to insert in to DB.

So that I executed json.dumps in the same for inserting the same in DB.

I can be able to see that it was getting inserted in to DB as needed.

```
   invoice_data: {"dict_all_cost_total": "16872.4061451", "dict_total_all": {"c3362ca0-8810-4ab7-a5b2-3cb571815690": ["test_instance", "m1.tiny", "16797.8795147"]}, "dict_inbound": {"c3362ca0-8810-4ab7-a5b2-3cb571815690": ["test_instance", "m1.tiny", "98.6362838745"]}, "dict_volume": "0", "dict_compute": {"c3362ca0-8810-4ab7-a5b2-3cb571815690": ["test_instance", "m1.tiny", "16570.0"]}, "dict_floating": "4.5", "dict_outbound": {"c3362ca0-8810-4ab7-a5b2-3cb571815690": ["test_instance", "m1.tiny", "129.24323082"]}}
```

Now I need to get the values back and need to process the same.

I have framed some sample code for getting the values.

for data in data_new:

```
    data1 = json.loads(data)
    print data1
    print type(data1)

    dict_compute = data1['dict_compute']

    for dict_computes in dict_compute.iteritems():

            for dict_computes_items in dict_computes:

                    print dict_computes_items
```

Result is as follows:

```
<type 'tuple'>
{u'dict_all_cost_total': u'109776.13801', u'dict_total_all': {u'5477b2b2-91f8-4e4b-a5b0-8f4a32210915': [u'instance_for_demo', u'm1.tiny', u'109776.13801']}, u'dict_inbound': {u'5477b2b2-91f8-4e4b-a5b0-8f4a32210915': [u'instance_for_demo', u'm1.tiny', u'93072.0652571']}, u'dict_volume': u'0', u'dict_compute': {u'5477b2b2-91f8-4e4b-a5b0-8f4a32210915': [u'instance_for_demo', u'm1.tiny', u'16590.0']}, u'dict_floating': u'0', u'dict_outbound': {u'5477b2b2-91f8-4e4b-a5b0-8f4a32210915': [u'instance_for_demo', u'm1.tiny', u'114.072752953']}}
<type 'dict'>
5477b2b2-91f8-4e4b-a5b0-8f4a32210915
[u'instance_for_demo', u'm1.tiny', u'16590.0']
```

My aim is to get the values from the dict_computes.

```
instance_for_demo, m1.tiny etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your json back to a dict structure:

```
data_dict = json.loads(dat)

print(data_dict["dict_floating"])
```